# Object resize by scaling(programming related)

Tags: vectors

I made illustration so the explanation would be easier.

[image: visual]

**Problem:**

Basically, I want to do the green object resize(from each corner) by dragging it further from P(makes green object larger), getting closer to point P(makes green object smaller). This all needs to be done with [scale(sX, sY)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Transformations) SVG transform.

**Current solution:**

Here's how I do it now, calculate the vector OP distance, so the F point is loose user could drag it anywhere. Next, would be the distance between the OF. To get the scale step, divide the OF/OP.

I am not sure if this is a correct way to do it, or is there any easier ways? My solution is only working if the OF degree remains same as the OP.

**Update**

I made a mistake by describing the problem, all previously written problem statement remains. Here is updated visual:

[image: Update].

What changed from the visual perspective is that the user could drag the box from each red corners. The movement is shown with vector PF, if the vector comes closer to point O which means scaling the box smaller. By moving the F distance further from O and P should grow the box. Basically, the OP+PF =OF from old picture.

Comment: It is unclear to me, what you are asking. What is it that you drage further from $P$? Is it $F$? And how should it be used to resize the green rectangle? Keeping the aspect ratio? Maybe it is just me, but I have a hard time deciphering the problem.

Comment: Yes, the aspect ratio should remain same, the green rectangle has on each corner anchor points which is where the dragging begins. The end-point where the user could release the mouse is marked with point F, while dragging the F changes and causes the scale step calculation. I hope the problem is now clearer.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I still cannot infer from your description how exactly you want the dragging to affect the size. Combining your last statement "My solution is only working if the OF degree remains same as the OP." and your suggested scale ratio OF/OP I understand that dragging F along the line through O and P should simply move one corner of the green rectangle to F's position. Is that correct? What do you want to happen when dragging F away from that line?

Comment: I also take it that O=(0,0) remains the center of the figure throughout, so we are only scaling how far away from the origin the corners should be, correct?

Comment: What should happen when $F$ and $P$ coincide? Does the rectangle remain the same or shrink down to nothing?

Comment: @amd the scale step should be 1 so do nothing.

Comment: Risto, have you tried implementing my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the fact that you want to "scale the rectangle based on F's distance from P" this would be my recommendation (Although it's a little unclear to me how you want to scaling mechanics to work):
Get the distance of $F=(x_1,y_1)$ to $P=(x_2,y_2)$, $d$, using the distance formula.
$$d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$
Now what you are going to want to do create a scaling constant, $k$, which this can be any value so you're just going to have to play around with it and see what works well. From here you are going to  want to ask yourself
$$\text{is }OF\ge OP\text{ ?}$$
this is basically asking whether $F$ or $P$ is further from the origin by comparing the length of the vectors $\vec{OF}$ and $\vec{OP}$. If the answer to that question is yes, then $F$ is farther from the origin and the square must be enlarged, otherwise $P$ is farther from the origin and the square should be shrunk. Now I having done all this I would make the scale factor as follows
$$S=\begin{cases}
1+\frac{k\cdot d}{OP} &\text{ if }OF\ge OP \\
\frac{k\cdot d}{OP} &\text{ if }OF<OP
\end{cases}$$
Then just call `scale(S)`.